# How to avoid null value in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
    $(document).on("click", "label.radeem-textbox", function () {
        var txt = $(".mytxt").text();  
        $(".radeem-textbox").replaceWith("<input class='radeem-textbox redeem-textbox'/>");  
        $(".radeem-textbox").val(txt);
  return false;  
    });

    $(document).on("blur", "input.radeem-textbox", function () {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        $(this).replaceWith("<label class='radeem-textbox'></label>");  
        $(".radeem-textbox").text(txt);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="right-side-margin-top right-side-margin-bottom display-block add-to-wishlist">
       
 <label  class="add-to-wish radeem-textbox">Redeem a Coupon</label>
                        </a>
```

I have jquery code for label convert to textbox on click. But when i not enter nothing on textbox, the textbox and label is not showing.. So how to make textbox focused if not enter nothing..

```
<label  class="add-to-wish radeem-textbox">Redeem a Coupon</label>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "label.radeem-textbox", function () {
    var txt = $(".mytxt").text();       
    $(".radeem-textbox").replaceWith("<input class='radeem-textbox'/>");        
    $(".radeem-textbox").val(txt);
    return false;       
});

$(document).on("blur", "input.radeem-textbox", function () {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $(this).replaceWith("<label class='radeem-textbox'></label>");      
    $(".radeem-textbox").text(txt);
});
```

Comment: can you please make code snippet here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add with `if(txt.trim())`. [**trim()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) It will validate the input box is empty or not.Its only allowed its not `empty,null` .

```js
$(document).on("click", "label.radeem-textbox", function () {
    var txt = $(".mytxt").text();       
    $(".radeem-textbox").replaceWith("<input class='radeem-textbox'/>");        
    $(".radeem-textbox").val(txt);
    return false;       
});

$(document).on("blur", "input.radeem-textbox", function () {
    var txt = $(this).val();
  if(txt.trim()){
    $(this).replaceWith("<label class='radeem-textbox'></label>");      
    $(".radeem-textbox").text(txt);
    }
  else{
    console.log('enter text please')

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label  class="add-to-wish radeem-textbox">Redeem a Coupon</label>
```

***Alternative*** way is :
**update with label tag**
[**contenteditable**](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) its same as your thing

```html
<label contenteditable="true">Click me to edit me</label>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. now it is working fine for me.. Is this possible label text editable in textbox..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("blur", "input.radeem-textbox", function () {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    if($.trim(txt).length) { // if not empty value
        $(this).replaceWith("<label class='radeem-textbox'></label>");      
        $(".radeem-textbox").text(txt);
    } else {
       //empty value so focus again.
       $(this).focus();
    }
});
```